# CSS tooltip - line break at a certain width

Tags: css, sass

I have a CSS tooltip that just breaks every word. Instead i would like it to break a word only if a certain width is about to be exceeded, but I have no idea how to do it. I also can't just set a certain width since the tooltip could also contain one short word and would then be too wide.

http://jsfiddle.net/o9s4dy0t/7/

This is my CSS code currently:

```
.tooltip {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}



.tooltip:after {
    background: #111;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: .5em;
    bottom: 1.35em;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    display: block;
    padding: .3em 1em;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    max-width:calc(100vw-(100vw/2));
    right:0;
    z-index: 98;
}

.tooltip:before {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #111 transparent;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8) transparent;
    border-width: .4em .4em 0 .4em;
    bottom: 1em;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

BTW I'm using .scss files.

Comment: set a width to `.tooltip:after` and try

Comment: "I also can't just set a certain width since the tooltip could also contain one short word and would then be too wide."

Comment: Not that this fixes the issue, but you are using `calc` wrong - the `-` operator (and `+` likewise) _must_ be surrounded by whitespace.

Comment: The problem here is that the ::after pseudo element is absolutely positioned, so that the width calculation method becomes shrink-to-fit. While the max-width might prevent it from going beyond a certain width, I don’t think you’ll be able to stop it from shrinking as far as possible without a min-width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the display of the :after element to table or inline-table for the width calculation to work as you need it.

```css
.tooltip {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}



.tooltip:after {
    background: #111;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: .5em;
    bottom: 1.35em;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    display: table;
    padding: .3em 1em;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    max-width:calc(100vw - (100vw/2));
    right:0;
    z-index: 98;
}

.tooltip:before {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #111 transparent;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8) transparent;
    border-width: .4em .4em 0 .4em;
    bottom: 1em;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<p>Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test <a class="tooltip" title="aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa">TEST</a> test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</p>
```

PS: Though I have to ask why you are trying to implement your own tooltip;  It's a great exercise, but otherwise consider some thirdparty options.